# Python Regex solution for finding numbers not preceded by a set of characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex solution to find all numbers (arbitrary # of digits) that are not preceded by "p=" or "p = ". For example:

`5.5 vs 9.9, p = 0.01 and p = 0.05`

The regex should pick up 5.5 and 9.9, but not 0.01 or 0.05

I've tried using a negative lookbehind `(?<!p=|p\s=\s)(\d?\.?\d)` but it still returns `01` and `05`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't allow variable-width negative lookbehinds, but you can put more than one, and add one to guard against matching in the middle of a number.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!p=)(?<!p\s=\s)(?<![\d.])(\d?\.?\d+)', inp)
['5.5', '9.9']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match what you don't want, and an alternation with a capture group for what you want to keep. Using `re.findall` will return the capture group 1 values.

```
\bp\s*=\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bp\s*=\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match `p=` with optional whitespace chars between the equals sign, and match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `|` Or
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits with can optional decimal part

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8bEMQ/1).

```
s = r"5.5 vs 9.9, p = 0.01 and p = 0.05"
pattern = r"\bp\s*=\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
print([v for v in re.findall(pattern, s) if v])
```

Output

```
['5.5', '9.9']
```

Comment: This is super interesting - do you mind explaining further why adding the alternation leads to excluding the first expression?

Comment: @Alissa It is the behavior of [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `re.findall` followed by a list comprehension to filter the results:

```py
inp = "5.5 vs 9.9, p = 0.01 and p = 0.05"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:p\s*=\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', inp)
result = [m for m in matches if re.search(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$', m)]
print(result)  # ['5.5', '9.9']
```

The trick here is to match all floats/integers as well as `p = <some num>` values, the latter *first*.  We then retain only the numbers *not* preceded by `p =`.